# AnimationComplete on which object?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I apply an animation to the Canvas.BottomProperty of an Image to "roll up" the image when I want it to be hidden.

I am looking at the animation's Completed event.  The object made available to the handler is the AnimationClock, which has Timeline, which is the Animation itself.

I would like to know which Image this event has fired for, i.e., the Image on which I called BeginAnimation.  Is that not available, or am I just missing it?

One thing I have tried is to store the animation object in a dictionary and look it up in the Completed event handler.  However, what I have found is that the Animation referenced below as "timeline" is a different object than the one used in the BeginAnimation call.  In other words, the animation returned is apparently not the same as the one sent via

```
animatedImage.BeginAnimation( Canvas.BottomProperty, animation );
```

(The following code is before the call to BeginAnimation, of course.)

```
animation.Completed += ( o, e ) =>
{
    var timeline = ( ( AnimationClock ) o ).Timeline;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might define a helper method like this:

```
private static void AnimateProperty(
    UIElement element,
    DependencyProperty property,
    double toValue,
    Duration duration,
    Action<UIElement> completed)
{
    DoubleAnimation a = new DoubleAnimation(toValue, duration);
    a.Completed += (o, e) => completed(element);
    element.BeginAnimation(property, a);
}
```

and then call it like the following. In the example i'm setting the element invisible when the animated completes.

```
AnimateProperty(imageElement, Canvas.BottomProperty, -100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                element => element.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden);
```